# Sample Images not showing (Omega Kickstart theme)

Tags: theming

Sorry for this beginners question:
I made a fresh installation of Drupal 7 and then installed "Omega Kickstart" theme by copying the zip-isntallation-link under http://drupal.org/project/omega_kickstart

However, the file is only about 300 Kbit and indeed there is no sample images showing - in fact only one logo changed on my startpage and a slightly different formated text.

**Is it possible to install the theme with all the sample-images and modules?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Omega Kickstart](http://drupal.org/project/omega_kickstart) is just a theme; it doesn't contain any module. You are probably interested in the [Commerce Kickstart](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) distribution, which contains the Drupal Commerce module, and any of its dependencies.

> Commerce Kickstart is the quickest way to get up and running with Drupal Commerce. It includes the latest versions of Drupal core, Drupal Commerce, and the other modules it depends on. It also gives you a set of options to create a fully-featured demo store out of the box complete with an attractive theme, catalog and search configuration, and a custom back office interface.